# Error Page before response processing finishes

Tags: java, tomcat, timeout, httprequest

I have certain use case where processing can take upto 2 hrs of time. so once user submit the request from browser, my understanding was browser would keep on waiting for response to arrive. But I get error page after some 15-20 mins.

I understand that web request should not so much time consuming, but i stuck with the existing architecture and design.

Can some one suggest some solution for this problem.

I am using IE 9 as browser. Tomcat as server.

Comment: I finally did it using ajax. Seems thats the only option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do for similar issues is create a separate thread on the server and return a response to the user saying that job has been started and then either

- display the result of that job on a specific page (this seems like an acceptable solution, the user will probably not stay in front of his screen for such long task)
- or via ajax do some polling to have the status of the job you just triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the server timeout is about 15 min, therefore you get the error after 15 min. One solution is to increase the server timeout. But increasing to 2 hours would be too long. Another option is to poll the server from the browser to find out the status of the task. You can use ajax call for the purpose.